# App not working on Heroku after upgrading database

Tags: postgresql, scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I just recently upgraded my database on Heroku from the `Hobby dev` plan to the `Standard 0` plan. My application was working just fine on the Hobby Dev plan with regards to inserting data. I changed the `DATABASE_URL` to the new `DATABASE_URL`. I am receiving the correct credentials, which I have verified by printing them out. The new rows are not being inserted into the database though. Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Let me know if there is any other data I can provide to help you

Edit more data:

```
  override def database: DatabaseDef = {
      println("CREATING DATABASE FROM URL")
      val dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
      val username = dbUri.getUserInfo.split(":")(0)
      println("Username: " + username)
      val password = dbUri.getUserInfo.split(":")(1)
      println("password " + password)
      val dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost + dbUri.getPath
      println("url " + dbUrl)
      JdbcBackend.Database.forURL(dbUrl, username, password, null, "org.postgresql.Driver")
    }
  }
```

That is the method that I am trying to use to connect to my data source, which works when I am on the `Hobby Dev` postgres plan. The only difference that I can see is that `Hobby Dev` is postgres `9.3.5` while the `Standard 0` plan is `9.3.6`

EDIT 2:

I am using the play-slick dependency and this postgres dependency:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.8.1", 
  "org.postgresql"      % "postgresql"      % "9.4-1200-jdbc41" withSources() withJavadoc()
```

Comment: are you missing the port? What does 'dbUrl' look like in the println?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection setup does not include setting the port, and it is very likely that on your s0 plan, it's not 5432.

Parse out the port from the DATABASE_URL and pass that into jdbc however that's done.

Answer (score 0):

Will is correct. This is what it should look like:

```
def getConnection(): Connection = {
  val dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
  val username = dbUri.getUserInfo.split(":")(0)
  val password = dbUri.getUserInfo.split(":")(1)
  val dbUrl = s"jdbc:postgresql://${dbUri.getHost}:${dbUri.getPort}${dbUri.getPath}"
  DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password)
}
```